# Isekai Manhwa where a shut-in gets transported to another world where daily life objects can be used as weapons

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

I'm searching for a Manhwa I read a long time where a shut-in gets transported to another world but he can go back to the real world. He discovers that daily life objects can be used as weapons in the other world.

Example: One time he brought batteries to the other world and they exploded like bombs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Her Summon](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5skp6yy/her-summon)**

> Due to a misuse of a word joke on live TV broadcast, girl group otaku, 'Jin-Kyung' ended up becoming doxxed and labeled as a "child predator", and ended up getting Social Anxiety Disorder. 3 years later, because of his past incident from the 3D world, his love for only the 2D world manifested, and ended up becoming a "Shut-In Otaku"! Then one day, as Jin-Kyung was no-lifing as usual, he was summoned to ‘Another World’, and came face-to-face with a bright-eyed, hopeful Summoner… Interesting enough, in the world that Jin-Kyung was summoned to, his Social Anxiety Disorder disappeared, and he was also able to wield immense power, and became the strongest summoned being there ever was!! The story of a former girl group otaku turned powerful 2D otaku, and the story of a weak and feeble Summoner commences now!

[image: Front cover of Her Summon]

Comment: This is the one, thank you for the answer!